# C# Stripe create customer with default payment method not working

Tags: stripe-payments

In my workflow I am creating a new customer with a valid payment method and want to set that as default (to apply to subscription billing)

Based on the docs it seems if I'm using PaymentsIntent I need to set DefaultPaymentMethod inside InvoiceSettings and IntelliSense matches everything up as expected. https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method

When I actually create the options object (not even making the Create call) I get the below error

> {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.    at ... [offending code below]

```
var customerOptions = new CustomerCreateOptions
{
    Email = user.Email,
    Name = user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName,
    PaymentMethod = model.payment_method,
    InvoiceSettings =
    {
        DefaultPaymentMethod = model.payment_method
    }
};
```

If I remove the InvoiceSettings param everything works perfectly, except their payment method is not set as default. I have also tried with null in DefaultPaymentMethod, same error.

How can I, during customer creation, set their payment method as default?

Comment: Joshua, can you confirm that model.payment_method is a string like "pm_xxx"? This should work.

Comment: Correct, it is a string like that. And it works perfectly in the line just above `PaymentMethod = model.payment_method` same variable according to docs same req, I agree this should work :P

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full output of the error? Can you print out user.Email, user.FirstName, user.LastName and model.payment_method to confirm those are what we expect?

Comment: In case it's helpful, there are Stripe engineers available to chat during most business hours in the #stripe channel on Freenode (https://webchat.freenode.net/?channel=#stripe).

Comment: @w1zeman1p I'm 100% certain it's the InvoiceSettings param, if I remove that everything works perfectly, the customer gets created and their payment method saved ... only problem is their card isn't set as Default -- thanks for the freenode link

Comment: You're totally right. That invoice settings param should actually be `CustomerInvoiceSettingsOptions` not just the raw object like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to initialize an instance of `CustomerInvoiceSettingsOptions` to pass as the `InvoiceSettings` which you can do with the following:

```
var customerOptions = new CustomerCreateOptions
{
    Email = user.Email,
    Name = user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName,
    PaymentMethod = model.payment_method,
    InvoiceSettings = new CustomerInvoiceSettingsOptions
    {
        DefaultPaymentMethod = model.payment_method
    }
};
```

Comment: Happy to help! :D